# Local variable through router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, local-variables

My main component has a Back button, that is not always visible (depends on child component). How to get it working? I tried using local variable, with no luck.

In my app.component.html (parent) I have the following

```
<button *ngIf="child.goBackUrl">Back</button>
<router-outlet #child></router-outlet>
```

In ChildComponent I have

```
goBackUrl: string = "test";
```

This doesn't work. I need a way, where I can access child variables and methods from parent component. If I try to call method from parent that is inside child component, I get

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self._el_102.goBack is not a function

Any ideas? I've tried a few different things, but no luck

Comment: What is the parent, what is the child? Please post more code. You can't use binding with components added by the router (not sure if this is what you want).

Comment: But this is exactly what I need, binding with components added by the router. Or another way for AppComponent (main component) to access children components (added by router).

Comment: Can't you use `window.history.back()`?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: @AviadP. I could, but the button shouldn't be always available. There would also be "settings" button that opens a modal specific to a child.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'll check it out.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer communicating using service seems to work well, and quite a good solution. Add as answer if you want, or I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 data-binding works only for components and directives added statically to a components template (parent-child only).

For all other situations use shared services as demonstrated in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service